# C# equivalent to Java resource

Tags: c#, java

Is there an online resource or database that allows looking up the C# equivalent to a Java class and vice versa?

I have been porting code and have been Googling individual classes one at a time; it gets a little tedious. 8^j

Cheers

Comment: You already found the resources I use most: Google and Stackoverflow.

Comment: A good reason to start making one?

Comment: DIY, and then dedicate a blog entry to it so the rest of us can reap the benefits! :D

Comment: It may be tedious, but I bet you're learning a lot more than you would if given a shortcut.  Silver lining?  I face the same issues when trying to do something in Java that I can do off the top of my head in .NET, so I feel your pain, but really, the learning will stick in your head better if you have to work harder at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something as simple as this: http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/java_csharp_comparison.html

or more about the libraries available on each?

Answer (score 0):

1 * Google "C# api" = http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d11h6832(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

[Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/) is a nice approach, though it is more comprehensive than you're after.  The goal of the site is to show the same task being done in as many languages as possible. For example, for [File IO](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/File_IO), you could search for the Java and C# versions and compare them.